# find out which browse button clicked in a repeater and append progress bar under particular clicked browse button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have attached browse button in each row of repeater and on click browse button selected files display with progress bar but i am facing problem when I click any browse button progress bar  always display in the first row of repeater. Actually i am unable to find out which button has clicked in a repeater.I have to append progress bar and file name of particular clicked browse button.My code is as follows:

```
<html>
      <head runat="server">            
       <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <style>
        .a{
        display:none;
        }
        .input{
        display:none;
        margin-top: -17px;
        margin-left: 176px;
        width:34px;
        }
        .button {
            background: #25A6E1;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#25A6E1),color-stop(100%,#188BC0));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
            filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#25A6E1',endColorstr='#188BC0',GradientType=0);
            padding:8px 13px;
            color:#fff;
            font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
            font-size:17px;
            border-radius:4px;
            -moz-border-radius:4px;
            -webkit-border-radius:4px;
            border:1px solid #1A87B9;
            width:227px !important;
        }   
        </style>
         <script>

             var selDiv = "";
             var updateProcessInterval;
             var updateTextBoxInterval;

             document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

             function init() {
                 // var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("files");
                 //  alert(classname);
                 // document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
                 var f = document.querySelectorAll('.files');
                // alert(f);
                 for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
                     //alert("jdj");
                     //alert(f.length);
                     f[i].addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);

                     //alert(f[i]);
                     /* for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
                     alert(classname.length);
                     classname[i].addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
                     }*/
                     //  $('.files').on("change", function(){ handleFileSelect(); });
                 }
             }
             function handleFileSelect(e) {

                 if (!e.target.files) return;

                 var files = e.target.files;
                // alert(files);

                 for (var i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {

                     var progress = document.createElement("progress");
                     progress.setAttribute('class', 'a');
                     progress.setAttribute('id', 'i');
                     progress.setAttribute('max', '100');
                     progress.setAttribute('value', '0');
                     var filename = document.createElement("div");

                     var text = document.createElement("input");

                     text.setAttribute('class', 'input');
                     text.setAttribute('value', '0%');
                     text.setAttribute('max', '100%');

                     filename.setAttribute('class', 'filename');
                     $('.prrogress-wp').append(filename);
                    $('.progress-wpr').append(progress);
                    $('.progress-wpr').append(text);
                 }


                 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
                 var filename = document.getElementsByClassName('filename');
                 var textname = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
                 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                     var f = files[i];
                     var p = elements[i];
                     var t = textname[i];

                     filename[i].innerHTML = f.name;
                     p.style.display = 'block';
                     t.style.display = 'block';

                     updateProcessInterval = setInterval(update_progress, 1500);
                     updateTextBoxInterval = setInterval(updatetextbox, 1500);
                 }

             }
             function update_progress() {
                 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');

                 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                     var p = elements[i];


                     var a = p.value;
                     a = a + 10; //alert(a)// infinite number of times sum 
                     if (a > 100) {  //if this part add then see
                         clearInterval(updateProcessInterval);
                     }
                     p.value = a; //alert(p.value);

                 }
             }
             function updatetextbox() {
                 var textt = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
                 //alert(textt.length);  //any alert in this doc display right value but n no times
                 for (var i = 0; i < textt.length; i++) {

                     var tt = textt[i];
                     // alert(textt[i]);
                     var a = tt.value;
                     c = parseInt(a) + parseInt("10");

                     if (parseInt(c) > 100) {
                         clearInterval(updateTextBoxInterval);
                         return;
                     } else if (!(parseInt(c) < 0 || isNaN(c))) {
                         tt.value = c + "%";
                     }


                 }
             }


            </script>


        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
              <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1"   runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <HeaderTemplate>

            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
            <table id="gg">
            <tr class="ff">
            <td>
                 <input type="file" class="button files"  id="files" name="files"  onchange="handleFileSelect(this)"  multiple><br/>
                <div id="progress-wpr" class="progress-wpr">
                <div class="filename"></div>
                <progress class='a'  max=100 value=0></progress>
                <input type="text" value="0%" class="input"  max="100" />

                </div>
                <input type="submit"  value="Upload" class="button" style="margin-top:56px;width:77px !important" >
                  </td></tr></table>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>

          </div>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Please help me to find out clicked button in repeater so that i can append progress bar in it.Thanks in advance....

Comment: Where's the Browse button?

Comment: in repeater td  input type file

Comment: Ok, you are passing "this" to handleFileSelect(this) function. So, "this" represents the current FileUpload (Browse) control.

Comment: So, in function handleFileSelect(e){...} e represents the current control. Further, if you get the ID of that you could get the row number from the serial number in the ID string.

Comment: no i am unable to get id